# How can I query the NFTs associated with an account on a local test environment?

Tags: nft, dapp-development, alchemy

I wrote a smart contract which enables accounts to purchase NFTs. I now want to display the NFTs bought and associated with the connected account on a website.
The Alchemy API seems to be a good choice, but I have not found any examples of how to use it in development.

Can someone link me to an example on how to use Alchemy in development, or some other API that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this to set up the metadata to display the NFTs bought and associated with the connected address on a website:

https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-get-all-nfts-owned-by-an-address

Comment: Thank you. But my answer was about how I can query a local node to display the data

Comment: You have different questions on the title vs. description. One asking about how to query the NFTs associated with an account on a local test environment and the other about linking to an example on how to use Alchemy in development, or some other API that you could use.

Comment: No, it is about how to use alchemy or something equivalent IN A LOCAL TEST ENVIRONMENT. you posted about how to do this just in general